# Race Conditions with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to asyncio and I was wondering how you prevent race conditions from occuring.  I don't see implementation for locks - is there a different way this is handled?

Comment: If you're going to downvote the question could you at least tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asyncio only runs one coroutine at a time and only switches at points you define, so race conditions aren't really a thing.  Since you're not worried about race conditions, you're not really worried about locks (although technically you could still get into a deadlock situation if you have 2 coroutines that wake each other, but you'd have to try really hard to make that happen)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.